# ReferenceError: System is not defined in java script

Tags: javascript

I am new to ES6.I am trying to run an ES6 web page in browser through `index.html` file.

The `index.html` content as below.

```
<script type='traceur-runtime.js'></script>
<script src='app-build.js'></script>
```

I have compiled the code using Traceur compiler, using `"Traceur --out newtraspiled.js oldmain.js"`.

The, error is :

> "ReferenceError: System is not defined".

Please help, if I need to add anything in System.js or runtime.js

It has created the final js file like below.

```
System.registerModule("module1.js", [], function() {
"use strict";
```

.
.
.

```
System.get("appl1.js" + '');
```

Thank you

Comment: How did you include `System.js`?

Comment: Thank you. I got the result. However, didnot get why the error was, coming ,though the 'system.js' called in 'index.html' earlier.